# How do I setup a custom ListView with divider using Android?

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I wanted to implement Pull to Refresh feature in my android application, so I implemented this library: [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). However, I can't seem to set custom style to divide programmatically.

The code is simple:

```
list = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
int[] colors = {0, 0xFF97CF4D, 0}; 
list.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
list.setDividerHeight(1);
```

However, it is throwing this error: `The method setDivider(GradientDrawable) is undefined for the type PullToRefreshListView` and `The method setDividerHeight(int) is undefined for the type PullToRefreshListView.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PullToRefreshListView` is not a `ListView`, hence that error. You should access the `ListView` inside `PullToRefreshListView` and invoke `setDivider*` methods on that.

```
list = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
int[] colors = {0, 0xFF97CF4D, 0};
ListView inner = list.getRefreshableView();
inner.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
inner.setDividerHeight(1);
```

As an alternative you could define your gradient as an XML drawable and set the attributes right in your layout like shown in the sample [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/sample/res/layout/activity_ptr_list.xml)

eg:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
  android:divider="@drawable/fancy_gradient"
  android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"...
```

Comment: It gives the error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ListView to PullToRefreshListView`

Comment: check the code above: you should invoke `getRefreshableView()` on your `PullToRefreshListView`. Casting to ListView is useless in this case. I'll get rid of that in my answer.

Comment: The code didn't work. I ended up styling the divider with an XML drawable. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: XML-based solution is working out-of-the-box. But I'm sure of the code-based solution as well. I suppose your `list` reference is a `PullToRefreshListView`, while in the modified snippet I assumed that as a `ListView` one. I'll slightly modify my answer in order to recover this issue.